# Docker Base Image Size configured in daemon.json

Tags: json, docker, daemon

Moving docker daemon configuration from CMDto /etc/docker/daemon.json. I placed below to change base image size from default 10.7G to 20G but daemon failed to start

```
{
  "storage-opts": [
     {"dm.basesize": "10G" }
  ],
  "graph": "/home/ashwaghmare/docker/docker-data"
}
```

~

Comment: ' Jan 05 02:34:27 docker[16662]: time="2017-01-05T02:34:27-08:00" level=fatal msg="unable to configure the Docker daemon 
with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type.json: 
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string\n" '

Answer (score 10):

Change in syntax helped configure base image size

```
{
  "storage-opts": ["dm.basesize=20G"],
  "graph": "/home/ashwaghmare/docker/docker-data"
}
```